# How to remove Node js script from pm2 windows startup

Tags: node.js, startup, pm2

I followed the below steps to add my js script to startup in my windows and its working.

1.npm install pm2 -g

2.npm install pm2-windows-startup -g

3.pm2-startup install

4.pm2 start myApp.js

5.pm2 save

6.reboot

7.pm2 ls

Now I wanted to remove my script from startup. How do I do it?

Comment: have you try `pm2 delete` command?

Comment: I tried. But after reboot i can see that program running in pm2 ls.

Answer (score 0):

From [the official README](https://github.com/marklagendijk/node-pm2-windows-startup):

### Uninstall

```sh
> pm2-startup uninstall
```

This removes the registry entry that starts the process on startup

---

The [document in npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-startup) seems out-of-date, I found the above announcement from their GitHub repo.

Comment: Yeah pm2-startup uninstall worked for me.